# How do you set the size of the x and y axis labels in manim?

Tags: python, manim

My setup_axes method that is inside my class shown below. But I don't know how to set the label sizes

```
def setup_axes(self):
    GraphScene.setup_axes(self)
    init_label_x = 1970
    end_label_x = 2018
    step_x = 2
    init_label_y = 100
    end_label_y = 600
    step_y = 100

    self.x_axis.add_numbers(
        *range(init_label_x, end_label_x + step_x, step_x),
    )
    self.y_axis.add_numbers(*range(init_label_y, end_label_y + step_y, step_y))

    self.play(ShowCreation(self.x_axis), ShowCreation(self.y_axis))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

`graph_scene.py` uses `NumberLine` to make its axes. And `NumberLine` has a config entry called `'number_scale_val'`

To be able to set this, go into `graph_scene.py` and in config, add the line

```
"x_label_font_size": 0.75,
```

Then within setup_axes, x_axis, around line 78 (I have already made edits so it may differ), add this line

```
number_scale_val = self.x_label_font_size,
```

So it looks like this:

```
self.x_leftmost_tick = self.x_min
x_axis = NumberLine(x_min=self.x_min,
                    x_max=self.x_max,
                    unit_size=self.space_unit_to_x,
                    number_scale_val=self.x_label_font_size, #<== this line added
                    tick_frequency=self.x_tick_frequency
                   )
```

Do the same for the Y axis and then in your class, add these lines in the config (change 0.5 to whatever you like):

```
"x_label_font_size": 0.5,
"y_label_font_size": 0.5,
```

Then you're good to go - you can set the size of the font in your axes